# Error loading css file in webpack

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader

i am trying to load a css file with webpack but i keep getting this error message as shown in the picuture.

[image: pics showing error]
i have done a lot of searching so please don't, all questions don't seem to fit my case.

below given are the various file am working with

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "loading_files",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
   }
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
"use strict"

let path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./src/index.js",

  output: {
    filename: 'bundler.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
 module:{
   rules: [
            {
              test: "/\.css$/",
              use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
         ]
       }
 }
```

### index.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import css from './index.css';

function component() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');
  element.classList.add('hello');
  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

### index.css

```
.hello{
  color: red;


 }
```

am currently using `webpack v4.6.0` and `npm v5.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `webpack.config.js`,

please remove the `""` from the `regex` expression.

```
// Whatever else you got here
rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
    }
]
```

Comment: thanks alot @Ru, so why didn't it work with "`/\.css$/`" ??

Comment: Hi @lilfancy Regex does not work with `""`. I believe `""` will cause the regex expression to become a string instead of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your webpack config file should not have the file extension `.json`.
Please change the extension to `.js`

Also, you need to tell webpack, that you want to use a config file and give it the path to this file. In your package.json, please modify the following prop:

```
{
   scripts: {
      "compile": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would do the corrections and get back to you @Daniel